# External process to handle couchdb notification causes crash

Tags: python, process, crash, couchdb

I am having trouble handling changes to my couchdb database through a python script.

```
data = 'test'
f = open('/home/username/test','w')
f.write(data + '\n')
f.close()
```

this is the script I try to run (for test purpose).
It's called "list.py" and it's located in "/usr/local/src/couchdb".
I modify my "local.ini" in my "/etc/couchdb" folder adding:

```
[update_notification]
list = python /usr/local/src/couchdb/list.py
```

This script should be called every time a modification is made, however it causes couchdb to crash almost as soon as I start the server.
This it the log of the error (I think).

```
 [Sat, 24 Oct 2015 23:05:09 GMT] [error] [<0.6468.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                  {<0.6468.0>,crash_report,
                   [[{initial_call,
                      {couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}},
                     {pid,<0.6468.0>},
                     {registered_name,[]},
                     {error_info,
                      {exit,
                       {exit_status,1},
                       [{gen_server,terminate,6,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,744}]},
                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},
                     {ancestors,
                      [couch_db_update,couch_primary_services,
                       couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
                     {messages,[]},
                     {links,[<0.5922.0>]},
                     {dictionary,[]},
                     {trap_exit,false},
                     {status,running},
                     {heap_size,987},
                     {stack_size,27},
                     {reductions,884}],
                    []]}}

 [Sat, 24 Oct 2015 23:05:09 GMT] [error] [<0.5922.0>] Update notification 
 process <0.6468.0> died: {exit_status,

 [Sat, 24 Oct 2015 23:05:09 GMT] [error] [<0.6430.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                  {<0.6430.0>,supervisor_report,
                   [{supervisor,{local,couch_db_update_notifier_sup}},
                    {errorContext,child_terminated},
                    {reason,normal},
                    {offender,
                     [{pid,<0.6467.0>},
                      {name,"list"},
                      {mfargs,
                       {couch_db_update_notifier,start_link,
                        ["python /usr/local/src/couchdb/list.py"]}},
                      {restart_type,permanent},
                      {shutdown,1000},
                      {child_type,supervisor}]}]}}

 [Sat, 24 Oct 2015 23:05:09 GMT] [error] [<0.6472.0>] ** Generic server <0.6472.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {#Port<0.5590>,{exit_status,1}}
** When Server state == {os_proc,"python /usr/local/src/couchdb/list.py",
                             #Port<0.5590>,
                             #Fun<couch_os_process.2.14837184>,
                             #Fun<couch_os_process.3.14837184>,5000}
** Reason for termination == 
** {exit_status,1}
```

What am I missing? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, It seems that and external process that handles notification in couchdb needs an infinite loop where stdin is read each time it is presented otherwise it does not work.

```
import sys

line = str(sys.stdin.readline())
while line:
    print(line)
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

for example this code (python) reads every notification and prints it...

Comment: I get line as empty always. Any idea on that? Here is my python script

    'line = str(sys.stdin.readline())'
    while line:
    fromaddr = 'lollyssium@gmail.com'
    toaddrs  = 'asifkamal71@gmail.com'
    msg = line + ' There are some changes..'

    username = 'emailid'
    password = 'password'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()
    line = sys.stdin.readline()

Answer (score 0):

Does the couchdb process have permission to read/write to the file in your script? It might be owned by you, and the couchdb process might not have access to write to it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... both the script and the destination directory are in 777 mode.

Comment: You're writing to the "username" directory, which might not be accessible by the couchdb process.

Comment: Try writing to something like `/var/log/test` (and make sure permissions are set correctly for the test directory so that couchdb can write to it)

Comment: I found what was wrong. The problem were not the permission but couchdb notification system since it requires an infinite loop where stdin is read each time it is presented otherwise it does not work. Thanks anyway. P.s. Should I answer my own question then close it or what?